# How to compare an array string with a range value

Tags: excel, vba

I've pulled out unique person's names in a dictionary and then put them into an array:

```
'Extract the dictionary's keys as a 1D array
    Dim result As Variant
    result = dic.Keys
```

That works fine - I can see the unique names in the array called result - Jane, Bob, etc. with: MsgBox Join(result, vbCrLf)

Its using a loop variable called valCounter2 so I should be able to loop through the array with result(valCounter2)

Now I'm trying to look for those names in column CX:

```
    Dim LSearchRow As Integer
        LSearchRow = 2
        While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
            If Range("CX" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = result(valCounter2) Then
```

The last line is the problem.  If I set that line to a real value then it works.  So this works:
**If Range("CX" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "Jane Smith" Then**

How do I get it to use the array variable?

Comment: Would it be better to leave the dictionary as is and loop the range and use the `.exists` of the dictionary object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate between array elements, or using Match to check if the string exists. Please, try the next code:

```
Sub CheckArrayElements()
  Dim LSearchRow As Long, mtch As Variant
        'result should be take from somewhere else...
        LSearchRow = 2
        Do While Len(Range("A" & LSearchRow).Value) > 0
            mtch = Application.match(Range("CX" & LSearchRow).Value, result, 0)
            If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'the string has been found
                'do here what you need
            End If
            LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
        Loop
End Sub
```

The above sub only shows you how to proceed with an array, in order to do the comparison.

If the array comes from a Dictionary and you do not want only learning about arrays, it is much simpler to follow the suggestion you received in the first comment.

Comment: I'm starting with 6 rows with 4 unique names.  Now its giving me 24 rows so the combination.

Comment: @Transitioned The above code is independent of number of rows and unique names. You must take care that between the second row and the last one **an empty cell must NOT exist**, because in such a case it will exit the loop. If it is possible to be such empty cells, please state it and I will adapt the code to handle such a situation, too. Now, do you want learning how to check a range against an array, independent of its provenience, or to one coming from a Dictionary? In the last case, the code should be simpler (see the first comment placed by Nathan_Sav).

Comment: Sorry not understanding.  My problem was how to use the unique names I've stored to match and then do actions.  When I saw result in the line:                                         
mtch = Application.Match(Range("CX" & LSearchRow).Value, result, 0)                                I thought that meant the value stored in the result array.  Not true?

Comment: @Transitioned What don't you understand (from  my comment)? Why do you think  that the above code will not solve your problem, independent of number or rows or elements in the array? **Did you try it**? And yes, as I commented on code, it will match the cell value with one of the array elements and do something only if such a match exists.

Comment: Yes thank you for the code I have tried it.  That is what is giving me the 24 rows.

Comment: @Transitioned I'm afraid I cannot get you. Does the code work as you need or not? How the code to "give you" rows?

Comment: In case it helps with more info here's what I've tried now and it gives me 24 sheets with one row

Comment: @Transitioned I have no any idea about **what you tried**... You did not show us anything about the part where the code should do something, if the condition is met. Is these "24 sheets with one row" anything wrong? Without sharing the code you use, I cannot understand anything from what you are talking about. I am not a mind reader...

Comment: Sorry its my first post.  I'm trying to work out how to add more code - I only seem to be able to comment.

Comment: Hi Fane I've posted the code on a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907400/matching-a-unique-value-from-an-array-to-trigger-actions

Comment: @Transitioned I am afraid I need to know something else before looking to the new question. May I know if the above code answered your question? I mean, **does it what you asked for**? If yes, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works.