# Matching a unique value from an array to trigger actions

Tags: excel, vba

Continuation of this question: [How to compare an array string with a range value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905170/how-to-compare-an-array-string-with-a-range-value)

What I want the code to do is find each row that matches a name - e.g. Jane Williams stored in the Result array.  And copy those rows to a new sheet.

This is the state of the code now.
Its giving me 24 new sheets with one row of data on them

```
'Loop through array and create and save new spreadsheet for each person's name
   Dim valCounter2 As Long ' loop counter
   Dim wb As Workbook
    For valCounter2 = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        ' Check loop MsgBox result(valCounter2)
          
            Dim LSearchRow As Long, mtch As Variant
                  'result should be take from somewhere else...
                  LSearchRow = 2
                  Do While Len(Range("A" & LSearchRow).Value) > 0
                      mtch = Application.Match(Range("CX" & LSearchRow).Value, result, 0)
                      If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 'the string has been found
                          
                          'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
                                Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
                                Selection.Copy
            
                            
                                'Create new worksheet with the person's name
                                Sheets.Add.Name = result

                                Sheets(result).Select
                                Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
                                ActiveSheet.Paste
                                
                            'Move counter to next row
                                LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
                                
                            'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
                                Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                                
                      End If
                      LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1
                  Loop
```

Comment: I think you must firstly learn asking a question... What problem do you have with the above code? Do you like us to guess? Does the above code raise an error? If yes, what error, on which line? If not, what problem do you have? You are the one able to **ask a question**. How many sheets with how many rows in each do you like it to give you? Your question is not clear at all. In fact there is **no question**. You inform us about what its giving you. Is it good and you want us to be happy for you?

Comment: And where is the problem? Since we do not see the sheet you try processing, how to appreciate if "24 sheets" is good or bad? Which are your expectations and **why**? Based on what?